# Automatic zoom depending on extreme points

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I use OL 4.6.5.

I put some markers in a vector layer and have used a home-made thing to find the zoom, depending on how far from eachother the markers are placed (points from database). This is clumsy and coarse but it works...

Now I look for a function or other means to set the zoom automatically, depending on max and min lat and long. I couldn't make "fitExtent()" to work so I looked here and I found two solutions but I can only use this one:

```
var onChangeKey = vectorSource.on('change', function() {   if
(vectorSource.getState() == 'ready') {
    vectorSource.unByKey(onChangeKey);
    map.getView().fitExtent(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());   } });
```

It uses the "fitExtent()" in another way than I did but unfortunately it doesn't change the zoom from 2. The other solution is some wierd language??? JS console reports: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

There is an example page here: https://xerxx.se/zoomtest.html
The JScode is at the bottom. Both solutions I tried are there, the one quoted above is "in action".
My own clumsy code is also there - you will see it.

There must be a clever command for this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you adopted in your code is not necessary here as `vectorSource.on('change', function() {` is important only when you load asynchronously a source (Ajax calls).

Your code is synchronous e.g

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [placeOSM[1], placeOSM[2]]
});
...
```

Replace the block

```
var onChangeKey = vectorSource.on('change', function() {
  if (vectorSource.getState() == 'ready') {
    vectorSource.unByKey(onChangeKey);
    map.getView().fitExtent(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
  }
});
```

with

```
// fitExtent is now fit and second arg map.getSize() is now optional
// e.g http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit 
map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
```

Comment: Worked! Added padding for the marker. See above link. Great expl.